# Give dynamic ID to Angular template html

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have created a html template that is reused a couple times in a parent component but with different data passed on.

I have parent.component.html which has

```
    <child-component title="one"></child-component>
    <child-component title="two"></child-component>
    <child-component title="three"></child-component>
```

Which works just fine.

The thing is, in 'child-component' I have checkboxes and their corresponding labels. As you know, they need the *for* attribute to know when a checkbox is checked. As I have realized, Angular re-renders the child-component each time is called, like a clone, and the *for* attributes are all the same for each child-component, so checkboxes don't work. I want to be able to create dynamic *for* and *id* for each checkbox each time the child-component is called upon.

I tried to explain my problem as best as I could. Is such solution possible?

Comment: Can you share your child component code?

Comment: Yes. It is possible

Comment: It is possible. you need to dynamically set the checkboxes based on the Input decorator. Let's say on your child you have an @Input checkBoxId:String='1'. On checkboxes <checkbox [id]="checkBoxId"+ i>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @mynameisx comment, the solution was simpler than I thought.

As I have the title property passed on with a different value, that itself differentiates each child component. So in each child component, I wrote this for the *id* and *for* of the input:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{ title }} + Check">
<label for="{{ title }} + Check"></label>
```

The checkboxes work!

Comment: I know, but it doesn't and it won't.